# Ignoring a warning in lint

Tags: c++, c, lint, pc-lint

We use PC-Lint in our project for finding out any warning in the project. I want to ignore a specifc warning of a specific rule, I went through the documentation of the lint on how to supress the warning, I have used multiple methods shows below.

[image: First method of ignoring the lint warning]

[image: second method of ignoring the lint warning]

I have also multiple other methods, as shown below

```
//lint -e{551}
static ui16 new_var



static ui16 new_var  /* lint !e551 */


#define Suppress(n)

Suppress(551)
static ui16 new_var
```

but none of the methods are working, I am still getting the warning, if anyone could show me what am I doing wrong, would be grateful.

Comment: Please transcribe the content of images so that _everybody_ can access it. At the very least, "enter image description here" is an instruction that you are supposed to follow.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: If you're having difficulty with commercial software (this appears to be [Gimpel PC-lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC-Lint)?) surely the vendor would be the appropriate entity to ask for support? They're going to be best placed to help you.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings,version 8.0

Comment: https://gimpel.com/support.html

Comment: For the specific case of a parameter not being referenced, can you just change the function definition to `void f(int n, unsigned u, int)` (removing the name `k` entirely), indicating that, probably for API compatibility, the function is still called with three arguments, but the third is never used (and can't be now, it's impossible to reference it without the name).